# Minimum number of bit-flips to enumerate all bit-strings

Tags: binary, bit-strings

If you have an $n$-bit binary string initialised in $000...000$, and at each step you are allowed to flip a single bit, what is the minimum number of flips required to have arrived at every possible $n$-bit binary string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Gray code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) enumerates all possible strings with single flips, so $2^n$.